# How to change the background of a button just for a duration between its press and release?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to change the background of a button during the time of press and release. I am coding in c# universal windows platform. I am trying the following but failed.

```
 private void pay_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pay.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Pink);
    }

    private void one_FocusEngaged(Control sender, FocusEngagedEventArgs args)
    {
        one.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
    }
```

Comment: So you want the button to be white when pressed down and pink when not pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the style of your button, especially the *Pressed* VisualState. Sample:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use it:

```
<Button Content="Something" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Padding="20" Background="Pink"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pointer events to do that, but you have to manually add the handlers via the `AddHandler` method as you'll need to also be able to handle previously handled pointer events to make sure the UI stays consistent.

You can use this code:

```
MyButton.AddHandler(
  UIElement.PointerEnteredEvent, // The target event
  new PointerEventHandler((s, e) => 
  {
      // Handle your background here
  }), 
  true); // Include previously handled events
```

These are the events you'll need to use: `UIElement.PointerEnteredEvent`, `UIElement.PointerExitedEvent`, `UIElement.PointerCaptureLostEvent`, `UIElement.PointerCanceledEvent`, `UIElement.PointerReleasedEvent`.

You'll need to adjust the background of your button depending on the source event, as some of these methods are fired when the user starts pressing a button, and others when the button is released.

**Edit**: here's an example to add the handlers for when the button is released:

```
foreach (RoutedEvent target in new[] { UIElement.PointerExitedEvent, UIElement.PointerCaptureLostEvent,
                                        UIElement.PointerCanceledEvent, UIElement.PointerReleasedEvent })
{
    MyButton.AddHandler(target, new PointerRoutedEventArgs((s, e) => 
    {
        MyButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }), true);
}
```

Do the same for the `PointerPressedEvent` with another brush (when the button is pressed) and you should be all set.